# Why is the Motion Blur post processing effect not working in Unity (mac)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, blur, motion, post-processing

I just can't seem to get motion blur to work in my Unity game. I have added the Post Processing package, created a custom layer for it, added a Post Process Layer to my camera, a Post Process Volume object to my scene and I've linked them together using a dedicated layer. I've also added the effects I want to the Post Processing Profile.

I'm pretty sure I've done this all correctly as I have successfully added many post processing effects, including Bloom, Vignette, Depth of Field and Lens Distortion. These work fine. But when I add Motion Blur, despite turning the Sample Count to maximum, there simply doesn't seem to be a difference.

My scene is very simple at the moment, containing only a sphere with its normals inverted, centred around a user-controlled camera - the standard '360 Degree Photo' setup, basically. There are no lights and I am using a bright white ambient light to illuminate everything equally and optimally. The render pipeline is the default one for 3D games.

I have tried both spinning the camera AND spinning the sphere using the mouse. Neither seems to result in any appreciable blur. Anyone know why this is not working?

**Unity Version:** 2020.3.3f1 (Personal)

**Computer:** 2013 iMac

Comment: This won't help solve your issues, but it might solve your future players some eye-strain: please don't use motion blur or at least make sure it can be easily deactivated...